# renumbering references categories with splitbib

Tags: bibtex, splitbib

I am wondering if it is possible to renumber references in each category using the splitbib package. Here is my mwe, it is taken from the [splitbib documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/splitbib/splitbib.pdf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{splitbib}
\begin{category}[A]{First category}
\SBentries{entry1,entry4}
\end{category}
\begin{category}[B]{Second category}
\begin{category}{First sub-category}
\SBentries{entry2,entry6}
\end{category}
\begin{category}{Second sub-category}
\SBentries{entry5,entry3}
\end{category}
\end{category}

\begin{document}
We cite~\cite{entry1,entry3,entry4,entry5}. Note that we cite neither \verb+entry2+ nor \verb+entry6+,even though they have been assigned a category.
defined in the last category. The first sub-category will then not appear in the bibliography.
% \def\SBlongestlabel{A1}
\SBtitlestyle{bar}
\SBsubtitlestyle{none}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{entry1} This is the first entry.
\bibitem{entry3} This is the third entry.
\bibitem{entry4} This is the fourth one.
\bibitem{entry5} This is the last one.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

This mwe gives:

[image]

I cannot find a way to start numbering the second category from 1 so that it would be [B1], [B2] instead of [B3], [B4]. Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Your example doesn't compile in my system. I had to add empty lines after the `\bibitem`.

I don't think that splitbib has (unlike biblatex) a built-in option to do this. But you can try to reset `\@listctr` in the category title. At least in your example it works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{splitbib}
\makeatletter 
\begin{category}[A]{First category}
\SBentries{entry1,entry4}
\end{category}
\begin{category}[B]{Second category\setcounter\@listctr{0}}
\begin{category}{First sub-category}
\SBentries{entry2,entry6}
\end{category}
\begin{category}{Second sub-category}
\SBentries{entry5,entry3}
\end{category}
\end{category}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
We cite~\cite{entry1,entry3,entry4,entry5}. Note that we cite neither \verb+entry2+ nor \verb+entry6+,even though they have been assigned a category.
defined in the last category. The first sub-category will then not appear in the bibliography.
% \def\SBlongestlabel{A1}
\SBtitlestyle{bar}
\SBsubtitlestyle{none}
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{entry1} This is the first entry.

\bibitem{entry3} This is the third entry.

\bibitem{entry4} This is the fourth one.

\bibitem{entry5} This is the last one.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While it does work on the mwe, the proposed solution does not seem to work for my document, I get an error message "Missing \endcsname inserted". But, as you mentioned, I believe biblatex is my way out...